# Inserting Elements In Array As an Object but without using keys in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, insert, key

Current Situation **:**

```
[{
   "Severity":1,
   "Name":"Yash"
 }, {
   "Severity":2,
   "Name":"Yashaswi"
}]
```

Desired Situation **:**

```
[{1: "Yash"}, {2: "Yashaswi"}]
```

Code being used **:**

```
widTags = ["Severity","Name"];
let tempobj = {};
for(let key in widTags) {
  tempobj[key]=prop;    
}
dataArrayWid.push(tempobj)
```

Comment: `Desired Situation` is invalid syntax, so, you can't do that at all - did you want `[[1,"Yash"], [2,"Yashaswi"]]` - and how does that code achieve anything? where is `Yashawi` and `Yash` magiced from? and what is `prop`

Comment: @Bravo I think "Desired Situation" is not intended to be part of the code, so the code starts with `dataArrayWid =`

Comment: no, I think the achieved and desired situation are what OP's code currently do, and what they want to do - based on the partial snippet of code ... `dataArrayWid` is being created

Comment: `{1,"Yash"}` object requires key value pairs. your desired solution you are probably looking for an array of arrays?

Comment: @Bravo I get your meaning now -- OP was typing commas instead of colons in their Object literals. Thought I would've noticed that at first glance!

Answer (score 1):

This solution does what you're suggesting without changing the syntax too much from your original code:

```js
const original = [
  {"Severity":1, "Name":"Yash"},
  {"Severity":2, "Name":"Yashaswi"}
];
const final = [];

for (const oldObj of original){ // (Prefer `for...of` to iterate Arrays)
  const
    newObj = {},
    key = oldObj["Severity"],
    val = oldObj["Name"];
  newObj[key] = val; // Uses Severity val as prop name & Name val as prop val
  final.push(newObj);
}
console.log(final);
```

---

**And this is a more concise version:**

```js
const
  original = [ {"Severity":1, "Name":"Yash"}, {"Severity":2, "Name":"Yashaswi"} ],
  final = original.map(obj => ( { [obj.Severity]: obj.Name } ));
console.log(final);
```

**(Here, the [.map method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) of Arrays makes a new Array with each element modified by a function -- in this case an [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)).**

Note:

- The extra parentheses tell JavaScript that their contents are an expression containing our [Object literal to be returned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#returning_object_literals), not a block of code statements.
- Similarly, the extra brackets in the Object literal tell JavaScript that their contents are an expression specifying a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names), not a static property name,

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

**Demo :**

```js
const dataArrayWid = [{
   "Severity":1,
   "Name":"Yash"
 }, {
   "Severity":2,
   "Name":"Yashaswi"
}];

const result = dataArrayWid.map((obj) => {
    return {
    [obj.Severity]: obj.Name
  }
});

console.log(result);
```